# Copy and Past multiple rows. Ljava.lang.Object response

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a little script to automatically copy/past some data from one sheet to another sheet.

I've come up with the following script :

```
function test() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sLVRDzzOopFQrXLNtAYKfyBfJthCkjvK8xe_PtOmso0').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;

     for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
  // Dispatching Data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  var data1 = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A2:G2').getValues();

  sheet.appendRow([data1]);
  ss.deleteRow(2)
  }
}
```

It's working perfectly fine but return me the following response :

`Ljava.lang.Object response...` for each row.

What should I do ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your script then the simple fix is to change:

```
sheet.appendRow([data1]);
```

to:

```
sheet.appendRow(data1[0]);
```

because you only want the 1 row.

However I'm not sure what the point of your for loop is?  This might be a little cleaner:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID')
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var data1 = sheet1.getRange('Sheet1!A2:G2').getValues();
  sheet2.appendRow(data1[0]);
  sheet1.deleteRow(2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly. About the loop. What happen is that I have a unknown number of row uploaded in a sheet everyday. Since I want to save these data, I'm copying them on another sheet everyday. Does that make sens ?